# How do i filter a sql table by the TOP 1?

Tags: sql

I have a query that is filtered by SO Number. It also has a column that has a unique number generated each time the SO is updated. How can i alter my code so that not only will it be filtered by the SO Number, but also filter by the TOP 1, or highest count of the updated key?

Thank you! 
This is on SQL Server.  Should have specified earlier

Comment: Highest count? You can check against `MAX(column_name)` to get the highest value found in that column...

Comment: is ... ORDER BY unique_number_key DESC LIMIT 1 what you mean? If not, please elaborate a bit in your Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT whatever_you_want
    FROM whereever_it_is
    WHERE your_criteria
    ORDER BY so_number DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

which will give you the "highest" so_number, returning only one record even if there are several with the same value

or

```
SELECT whatever_you_want
    FROM whereever_it_is
    WHERE your_criteria
        AND so_number == MAX(so_number)
```

which will give all rows with that maximum value, returning all if there are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 SONumber
FROM ExampleTable
ORDER BY SONumber DESC
```

Or

```
SELECT MAX(SONumber)
FROM ExampleTable
```

Comment: Sure, if that's supported, but it commonly isn't

Comment: @Dan I know it's a pretty basic example :) But, what do you mean by if that's supported?  Do you mean the TOP keyword?

Comment: Yeah. For example, MySQL doesn't support it.

Comment: @Dan fair point - I'm just caught in a MS stack loop :)  Might be worth getting the OP to re-tag the question if it's MySql or MSSQL.

Comment: @Dan thinking about it.  I think LIMIT isn't supported by MSSQL.